# SQL Time Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble with a conversion of time.

I have a table called 'TotalTime' which is set to INT and holds the time in seconds only. I want to convert these seconds to days, hours, minutes, seconds e.g. 01d 09:26:43.

Now I will show you the code I am using:

```
SELECT [BuildID],[Product],[Program],


SUM(CASE WHEN [State] = 'Running' THEN cast(TotalTime as INT) ELSE 0 END) AS [Running],
SUM(CASE WHEN [State] = 'Break' THEN cast(TotalTime as INT) ELSE 0 END) AS [Break]


FROM [line_log].[dbo].[Line1Log]

GROUP BY [BuildID], [Product], [Program]
```

So as you can see I am grouping the [State] column and would like to display the results of 'TotalTime' in the format I mentioned above.

Now I have tried this code but it will not work as I cannot convert INT to VARCHAR

```
SELECT [BuildID],[Product],[Program],

SUM(CASE WHEN [State] = 'Running' THEN CAST(FLOOR(TotalTime / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(SECOND, TotalTime, '19000101'), 8) ELSE 0 END) AS [Running]

FROM [line_log].[dbo].[Line1Log]

GROUP BY [BuildID], [Product], [Program]
```

The above would not display it in the exact format I wanted either.

Just wondering if someone would be willing to help me on this one?

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert calculated seconds after summing and grouping:

And use `VARCHAR(8)` instead of `VARCHAR(5)`.

```
SELECT [BuildID],[Product],[Program],
    CAST(FLOOR([Running] / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, [Running], '19000101'), 8) AS [Running],
    CAST(FLOOR([Break] / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, [Break], '19000101'), 8) AS [Break]
FROM (
    SELECT [BuildID],[Product],[Program],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [State] = 'Running' THEN cast(TotalTime as INT) ELSE 0 END) AS [Running],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [State] = 'Break' THEN cast(TotalTime as INT) ELSE 0 END) AS [Break]
    FROM [line_log].[dbo].[Line1Log]
    GROUP BY [BuildID], [Product], [Program]
) T
```